# Integer Errors in Python

Tags: python, math, numbers, integer

So I made a very simple program that counts down from 99 (sings 99 bottles of beer) but I keep getting 1 of 2 errors

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("This program sings the song 99 bottles of beer on the wall")
lim = input("What number do you want it to count down from?")
def sing():
    global lim
    while int(lim) >= 0:
        if int(lim) != 1 or int(lim) != 0:
            print(lim, "bottles of beer on the wall", lim, "bottles of beer")
            print("Take one down pass it around...")
            print(lim, "bottles of beer on the wall")
            input("\nPRESS ENTER\n")
            lim -= 1
sing()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'
```

Then, when I change `lim -= 1` to `int(lim) -= 1`, it says `SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment`

Comment: Consider: `for bottles in range(lim, 0, -1): ....`

Comment: Are you on Python 2 or 3? Because `input()` and the `print()` function are used in Python 3, but your first script line reads: `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. Could you specify which one are you trying to run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to covert lim from a string to an integer. Try this:

```
lim = int(input("What number do you want it to count down from?"))
```

Comment: If you do this, you can also remove all of the other conversions peppered throughout `sing()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Python 2.x (you don't specify), use `raw_input` instead.

```
lim = int(raw_input("What number do you want it to count down from?"))
```

From there, you can remove all the checks to `int(lim)`, as `lim` is already an integer.

Comment: The first line of the OP code reads: `#!/usr/bin/env python`, but after `print` is used like a function (who knows, maybe it's from the `__future__`).

Answer (score 3):

You get that `TypeError` because `lim` is a string. And strings do not support a `-=` operator:

```
>>> s = '10'
>>> s -= 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'
```

What you need to do is to convert `lim` to integer, something like this:

```
lim = input('Insert number: ')
lim = int(lim)
```

Don't worry about `print` after, it can print integers too, not just strings :)

---

I'd also say that there's a main problem with your first line. Judging from your code, this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

since you're writing code with Python 3 syntax/fashion.

You could also get rid of the `global` statement:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def sing():
    print("This program sings the song 99 bottles of beer on the wall")
    lim = input("What number do you want it to count down from?")
    lim = int(lim)
    while lim > 1:
        print(lim, "bottles of beer on the wall", lim, "bottles of beer")
        print("Take one down pass it around...")
        print(lim, "bottles of beer on the wall")
        input("\nPRESS ENTER\n")
        lim -= 1
sing()
```

Comment: `input()` is perfectly valid syntax in Python 2.x, it just doesn't do what `raw_input` does.  `input()` evaluates the code in 2.x; in 3.x it merely reads it in.

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, but not in the way the OP use it. There would be no need for converting to integer after.